# Find most common elements in all rows uisng DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Hope you all doing well

I want to find the most common elements in a DataFrame the elements that appear in all rows

I have this function , but it's work only when the DataFrame have two rows.

```js
def find_common_elements(df):
    df = df.drop(['motif', 'frequency', 'motif_cleaned'], axis=1)
    df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
    # Get the set of elements in the first row
    common_elements = set(df.iloc[0])
    # Iterate over the remaining rows and update the common elements
    for i in range(1, len(df)):
        common_elements.intersection_update(set(df.iloc[i]))
    return common_elements
```

Please anyone can help

For example if i have this data # Sample data

```js
data = {
    'A': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'B': [2, 1, 2, 2, 1],
    'C': [1, 2, 0, 0, 2]
}
```

the most common elements here 1 and 2 that appear in all rows

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Try using [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [nlargest](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# sample data
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (20,5)), columns=list('abcde'))

# stack every column into one
# get the counts of each value
# return the 5 largest (you can change this to any number you want to return)
df.stack().value_counts().nlargest(5)

8    20 # number 8 occurs 20 times
9    12 # number 9 occurs 12 times
1    12 # number 1 occurs 12 times
5    12 # number 5 occurs 12 times
2    11 # number 2 occurs 11 times
```

## UPDATE

Try using [functools.reduce](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functools.html#functools.reduc) with [numpy.intersect1d](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce

# your sample dataframe
data = { 'A': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'B': [2, 1, 2, 2, 1], 'C': [1, 2, 0, 0, 2] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# use reduce with np.intersect1d
reduce(np.intersect1d, df.values) # -> array([1, 2])
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand me , i want to display only the elements that appear in all rows for example if i have this data # Sample data
data = {
    'A': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'B': [2, 1, 2, 2, 1],
    'C': [1, 2, 0, 0, 2]
}   So the most common elements here 1 and 2

Comment: @Myriam_2189 sorry, you are correct, I did misunderstand what you were looking for. Please see the update to my answer.